# How does writing to BIOS/UEFI work?

Tags: security, bios, uefi

I've been reading a lot about how BIOS works and how to avoid BIOS related attacks. I understand things like TPM, but what doesn't make sense to me is how do you actually set the processor in a mode that allows you to write to the BIOS?

I've been reading through the [Intel datasheet](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/atom-c2000-microserver-datasheet.pdf) for my processor. Page 480 talks about BIOS security for registers and page 474 talks about descriptor vs non-descriptor mode. From what I can tell, when running normally the processor runs in descriptor mode which has all sorts of security access restrictions.

How does a BIOS flash utility legitimately upgrade the BIOS? I would think those security protections would stop it from working, but clearly there is a mode which allows carte-blanche write access.

Edit: Does it have something to do with section 22.5.3 on page 478?